# Does Twitter have any short name like Facebook's fb.com?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Does Twitter have any short name like Facebook's `fb.com`? It would be easier to advertise Twitter accounts like Facebook pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twttr.com` redirects to `twitter.com`, so you could use `twttr.com/accountname`. But that only saves two letters and may not be recognizable to some.

However, the `@accountname` format is pretty universally recognized as the format of a Twitter account. That's what I'd use.

`t.co` is Twitter's URL-shortener and wouldn't be useful for this.

Comment: Also there's a certificate mismatch when using https. Twitter's cert is valid for twitter.com and www.twitter.com but not the twttr.com avatar.